# How can two threads access a synchronized block simultaneuously

Tags: java, multithreading

I was asked in an interview of how two threads can access a synchronized block simultaneously, but I cannot come up with a scenario it might happen. Is it possible for two threads to access a synchronized block simultaneuously?

Comment: Remove synchronization? Why put it in 1st place if you want two thread to access it simultaneously?

Comment: The purpose of synchronized block(monitor) is that only one Thread owns the monitor at a given time. Can you please explain your case?

Comment: Just to make other responses more accurate: a "synchronized block" doesn't necessarily mean mutual exclusion of threads. Mutual exclusion will occur only if the threads are locking on the same monitor object. For example, it's completely legal for 2 threads to run Vector.add(..) simultaneously, provided that they operate on different vector instances.

Comment: I know this, but I recently faced this question in an Interview.

Comment: @Maestro: If that was the phrasing of the question, then yes, two threads can do it, if for example they enter a synchronized block on 'this', and they operate on 2 different instances of the class.

Comment: @Schneider Thanks for your reply. Could you please explain it with an example.

Comment: @Maestro This can be achieved using semaphores. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for having synchronized blocks is to prevent two threads from accessing that block simultaneously. This of course only holds if the two threads synchronizes over the same object. If you for instance does something like this:

```
synchronized (new Object()) {
// Multiple threads can execute here at the same time.
}
```

Multiple threads can then execute in the same block at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of a synchronized block is to prevent what you are asking, so you would have to remove the synchronized block.

Answer (score 1):

This **is possible** using [semaphores](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). Look at the code below:

```
// Create a semaphore with 2 permitted threads
private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create 10 threads which will call the critical section
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    criticalSection();
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
        t.setName("Thread No. " + i);
        t.start();
    }
}

private static void criticalSection() throws InterruptedException {
    // Try to enter the critical section (synchronized block)
    semaphore.acquire();

    System.out.println("Some heavy job. Thread ID = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    semaphore.release();
}
```

The semaphore only allows 2 threads to enter the synchronized block.

Answer (score 0):

Two threads **can not** access a synchronized block simultaneously.

Primary objective of synchronization is *to prevent concurrent access* to the same method/block by multiple threads.

From Java docs [Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

> Threads communicate primarily by sharing access to fields and the objects reference fields refer to. This form of communication is extremely efficient, but makes two kinds of errors possible: thread interference and memory consistency errors. The tool needed to prevent these errors is synchronization.

```
synchronized(object){
  //block of statements to be synchronized
}
```

Here, object is a reference to the object being synchronized.

> **A synchronized block ensures that a call to a method that is a member of object occurs only after the current thread has successfully entered object's monitor.**

**Some related links**

1. [javatpoint.com synchronization](http://www.javatpoint.com/synchronization)
2. [tutorialspoint.com java_thread_synchronization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If the threads entering the synchronized block see the same lock the block is defined on, then this is impossible.

However, if the question is regarding a "synchronized block" in general, without mentioning to the lock object/s being acquired, then this is allowed. For example:

```
public class MyStats {  
  private long total;
  private int count;

  public void add(long value) {
    synchronized(this) {
      this.total += value;
      this.count++;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final MyStats s1 = new MyStats();
    final MyStats s2 = new MyStats();

    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        s1.add(100);
      }
    };

    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        s2.add(200);
      }
    };
    ....
  }
}
```

In this example, since thread t1 operates on s1 and thread t2 operates on s2, there's nothing preventing the threads to be inside the synchronized block on the same time. The threads are using different locks. The mutual exclusion is determined by the lock instance, and not by the synchronized block, which only defines a scope.

Comment: Thanks Schneider. This is really helpful.